# How to print one of two sections of a page in javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I have two sections on my web page, SectionA and SectionB (2 HTML tables).

I want to be able to print the whole page, only SectionA or only SectionB.

I already have a CSS file with `media="print"` and I use `window.print()`.

To print the whole page, use your browser print button/menu item.

To print only SectionA :

```
function PrintSectionA()
{
    $('#SectionA').removeClass('hideFromPrint');
    $('#SectionB').addClass('hideFromPrint');
    window.print();
}
```

and the opposite for `PrintSectionB()`
Yeah! it works... almost. If I try to print only SectionA, **then** the whole page, I only get SectionA, because SectionB still has the hideFromPrint class.

What I'd want is :

```
function PrintSectionA()
{
    $('#SectionA').removeClass('hideFromPrint');
    $('#SectionB').addClass('hideFromPrint');
    window.print();
    $('#SectionB').removeClass('hideFromPrint');
}
```

But `window.print();` returns before the document is sent to the printer. So `PrintSectionA()` actually prints everything now :( .

Is there a way to make it work?

I think I saw somewhere that I can force a page break in CSS, I could ask the user to print the whole page but only select the 1st or 2nd page... not as fun!

Comment: Maybe a better solution is to create two CSS files for printing and just change the link to the print CSS file when a button or link is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

What about defining three functions (with one being "Print All")?

```
function PrintSectionA()
{
    $('#SectionA').removeClass('hideFromPrint');
    $('#SectionB').addClass('hideFromPrint');
    window.print();
}

function PrintSectionB()
{
    $('#SectionB').removeClass('hideFromPrint');
    $('#SectionA').addClass('hideFromPrint');
    window.print();
}

function PrintAll()
{
    $('#SectionA').removeClass('hideFromPrint');
    $('#SectionB').removeClass('hideFromPrint');
    window.print();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I dont have a "print all" button on my web page. The PrintAll function would need to be called by the browser before printing (using File>Print menu option) and I don't think there is an event for onPrint. I'll see with my boss, if I can add a print all button...